# Copying an unsorted C array into another while avoiding duplicates

Tags: c, arrays, copy, unique

Hello everyone and thanks for your time.

For exercise, I wanted to write a program which copies all elements from an array to another array but without the duplicates. The only condition is that I cannot change the original array - so no sorting.

I tried making a function which checks if the current element of array1 is found in the array we copy to (array2). If no, we then copy the element to the second array and *increase the size by one*.

However, it does not work:

If I have

```
int array1[15] = {3,2,4,7,9,1,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5};
int array2[15];
```

`array2` should contain the following numbers: `3,2,4,7,9,1,6,0,5`

But my output is as follows: `3,2,4,7,9,1,6`

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int already_exists(int array2[], int size_arr2, int element)
{

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<size_arr2; i++)
    {
        if(array2[i] == element)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int array1[15] = {3,2,4,7,9,1,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int array2[15];
    int i;
    int size_arr2=0;

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        int element = array1[i];

        if(already_exists(array2, size_arr2, element) == 1)
            continue;
        else
        {
            array2[size_arr2] = element;
            size_arr2++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<size_arr2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", array2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change for(i=0; i<9; i++) to for(i=0; i<15; i++)

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Such as running your program in a debugger and/or adding more debug prints? This may help: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Should be able to find the problem yourself with any basic debugging.

Comment: Why are you looping to 9 when there are 15 elements in the array?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description. Please be specific (and consider reading about hash tables).

Comment: Instead of repeating the array size in multiple places, which makes it easy to get out of sync like this, define a macro: `#define ARRAY_SIZE 15` and use that throughout the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the for loop

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++)
```

The array `array1` contains 15 elements. So the loop should look like

```
for ( i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
```

The reason of the error is that you are using "magic numbers" instead of named constants.

Nevertheless the program in whole is inefficient because the function `already_exists` is called for each element of the array `array1`. At least you could declare it as an inline function.

Moreover it should be declared like

```
int already_exists( const int array2[], size_t size_arr2, int element );
```

Instead of this function it is better to write a function that performs the full operation.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t copy_unique( const int a1[], size_t n1, int a2[] )
{
    size_t n2 = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < n2 && a2[j] != a1[i] ) j++;

        if ( j == n2 ) a2[n2++] = a1[i];
    }

    return n2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 15 };
    int array1[N] = { 3, 2, 4, 7, 9, 1, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int array2[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", array1[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t n2 = copy_unique( array1, N, array2 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++ ) printf( "%d ", array2[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3 2 4 7 9 1 4 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 
3 2 4 7 9 1 6 0 5
```